# I need to make css rule for this, but don't know what is the name

Tags: html, css

Here is the code

```
$('a[href^="something:"]').addClass('something');

#?????? {
background-image: url(images/elephant.png);
background-position: 0% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Can't figure out what should i replace question marks so css rule applys
Sorry about bad explanation and bad english

Comment: try with `.something` in place of `#??????`

Comment: 1. jquery code 2. ??? 3. profit

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to addd some class to every a tag that has some certain url? And you also want to add background-image for those anchors?

replace `#??????` with `.something` in this case.

Comment: This worked, just had trouble with # cause i didn't know i can left it out.

Comment: # refers to id and . refers to class. Check [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) for more!